# why filter function in python3 always returns empty result?

Tags: python, filter, generator

I am learning generator in python.

```
data = read_fake_data("./data/fake_data.csv") # genrator function
data_day = day_grouper(data) # generator function, group data by key
print("data grouped:",list(data_day)) 
# it prints:
# data grouped: [('2019-01-01', <itertools._grouper object at 0x000002294D296EB8>)]
# work well
```

then I want function #check_anomaly# to filter anomalous data:

```
ddd = filter(check_anomaly, data_day)
print("data filtered:",list(ddd))
```

only find that it prints empty list in console
I suspect error may occure in function , so I try to keep all data to debug:

```
ddd = filter(lambda x: x, data_day)
print("data filtered:",list(ddd))
```

It still returns empty result!

```
data filtered: []
```

Why is this happening? Can anybody help me with this???

Comment: After the first call to `list()` in `list(data_day)`, `day_data` does not have any more items. You should convert the generator to a list, save the result in a variable, and then use the saved list: `result=list(data_day)`.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense! Thanks a lot !!@DYZ